# How can I manage SQL CE databases in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0, sql-server-ce

I have Sqlserver 2005 Express Edition only. and VS 2005. How to i create my .sdf file. and how to create tables in that file...

I am developing a SmartDevice Application. if any possible to access the Sql server 2000 DataBase without using .SDF file.

Note: in my system i have VS 2005, SQL SERVER 2000, SQL SERVER 2005 Express Edition. And aslo i installed MS-SQL SERVER 2005 Compact Edition Developer SDK[ENU].

In my Sql server 2005 Studio, there is no any sqlserver compact edition in the EngineType Combo.

what are the things i need to do.. to perfectly run my application with Data Base.

Thanks, Thanks for previous one also.

Answer (score 0):

To manage your SQL Compact 3.1 database file from Management Studio Express, you must install Management Studio Express 2005 SP2.